# Clipboard in ionic v3 : Invalid providers

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I tried to integrate the **@ionic-native/clipboard** plugin in my app.module.ts file.

I have the following error message:

> [ts] Impossible d'assigner le type 'ClipboardOriginal' au type
>   'Provider'.   Impossible d'assigner le type 'ClipboardOriginal' au
>   type 'FactoryProvider'.
>       La propriété 'provide' est manquante dans le type 'ClipboardOriginal'. [2322] (alias) const Clipboard: ClipboardOriginal
>   import Clipboard

Have you a solution ?

My configuration is:

```
**Ionic Framework: 3.9.2 **
**Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.9 **
**Angular Core: ^5.2.10 **
**Angular Compiler CLI: ^5.2.10 **
**Node: 9.11.1 **
**OS Platform: Linux 4.15 **
**Navigator Platform: Linux x86_64 **
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: how did you import it into your app.module.ts

Comment: With the following line **import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard';**

Answer (score 2):

You need to import it in providers in your AppModule, before declating it as service inside your component

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...,
        Clipboard
    ]
    ...
})

export class AppModule
```

Comment: Thanks, I do that.